# Titanium - Can't use MapView

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator-titanium

I'm using ti.app in my Titanium project. Trying to create a MapView and add it in app main view. It doesn't work on a tablet nor with Genymotion emulator (I have a Virtual device with Google Apps installed). The error is the following:

```
[ERROR] GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
..
[ERROR] TiApplication: (main) [124,124] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;; Titanium 6.1.1,2017/06/26 16:09,undefined
[ERROR] TiApplication: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
```

No errors at compile time. I followed the [official documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Google_Maps_v2_for_Android-section-src-36739898_GoogleMapsv2forAndroid-InstalltheGooglePlayServicesSDK).

Answer (score 0):

I solved using [Nox App Player](https://www.bignox.com/) emulator.